# Lubridate; Dplyr how to aggregate a dataframe by week and category

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

consider the following example

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

time <- seq(from =ymd("2014-01-01"),to= ymd("2014-02-20"), by="days")
values <- sample(seq(from = 20, to = 50, by = 5), size = length(time), replace = TRUE)
tipe <- sample(rep(x = c("Tipe_A", "Tipe_B", "Tipe_C")), size = length(time), replace = TRUE)

df2 <- data_frame(time, tipe, values)

# A tibble: 51 x 3
   time       tipe   values
   <date>     <chr>   <dbl>
 1 2014-01-01 Tipe_B     40
 2 2014-01-02 Tipe_B     30
 3 2014-01-03 Tipe_A     35
 4 2014-01-04 Tipe_A     50
 5 2014-01-05 Tipe_B     35
 6 2014-01-06 Tipe_B     50
 7 2014-01-07 Tipe_A     50
 8 2014-01-08 Tipe_B     40
 9 2014-01-09 Tipe_A     30
10 2014-01-10 Tipe_B     25
# ... with 41 more rows
```

I would like to calculate the differentials between values and aggregate this dataframe by week and tipe.

I can do it only separated by type

```
df2 %>%
  filter(tipe == "Tipe_A") %>%
  mutate(diff = values - lag(values, order_by = time)) %>%
  group_by(week = week(time)) %>%
  summarise(avr = mean(diff, na.rm = T))

# A tibble: 7 x 2
   week    avr
  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1   7.5 
2     2 -20   
3     3   3.33
4     5   0   
5     6  -3.33
6     7 -10   
7     8  25
```

however I have a lot of types, so it would be a tedious process.

Is there a way to make it more efficient for each type?

Comment: I guess you need `df2 %>% group_by(tipe) %>% mutate(..`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, we may need to do the grouping by 'tipe' first, then calculate the 'diff', add the 'week' also as grouping column  before we get the `mean` in `summarise`

```
library(dplyr)
df2 %>%
   group_by(tipe) %>% 
   mutate(diff = values - lag(values, order_by = time)) %>%
   group_by(week = week(time), .add = TRUE) %>%
   summarise(avr = mean(diff, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Or do the `arrange` first

```
df2 %>%
   arrange(tipe, time) %>% 
   group_by(tipe) %>% 
   mutate(diff = values - lag(values)) %>%
   group_by(week = week(time), .add = TRUE) %>%
   summarise(avr = mean(diff, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: i take your recommendation and added `group_by(week = week(time), tipe) %>%` 
at first I thought there would be problems with the "lag" function taking wrong weeks / types.  but it works perfectly. Thanks